# Select each distinct field that is corresponds to another field in the same table

Tags: mysql, count, row, distinct

I have a problem with extracting data from one table.

Let's assume I have a table like:

t_stat with columns: statId, userId, country, installerId, date.

with values for example:

```
1, 1, Belgium, 1, 2014-04-06 18:19:03 ||
2, 2, Germany, 2, 2013-05-07 18:19:03 ||
3, 3, Italy, 3, 2018-06-08 18:19:03
```

What I need as a result:
i need to pick up every distinct country, and count how much installs it has on each date. It should look like this: 9 rows

```
2014-04-06 18:19:03 Belgium 1
2014-04-06 18:19:03 Germany 0
2014-04-06 18:19:03 Italy 0

2013-05-07 18:19:03 Belgium 0
2013-05-07 18:19:03 Germany 1
2013-05-07 18:19:03 Italy 0

2018-06-08 18:19:03 Belgium 0
2018-06-08 18:19:03 Germany 0
2018-06-08 18:19:03 Italy 1
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: What is the significance of the `18:19:03` time? Do you need the time included in your result set?

Comment: Distinct by date or by time?

Comment: Yes, I need this filed to be included in result, nothing, its just the way timestamp displays in db

Comment: So, brute force will be list all distinct time first, that for each time list each available country. The last would be to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial if you don't need the rows with zero values.

```
  SELECT DATE(date) date, country, COUNT(*) n
    FROM inst
  GROUP BY DATE(date), country
  ORDER BY date, country
```

But you do need them. So:

First you need to split your (denormalized) raw data up into three virtual tables for reference.

This virtual table gives you your countries.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT country FROM inst
```

This gives you your dates.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM inst
```

This gives you your counts of operations on each date in each country.

```
  SELECT DATE(date) date, country, COUNT(*) n
```

Then you need to join together these three virtual tables. Use `LEFT JOIN` for the last one so the zero values are not suppressed. And, use `IFNULL` to show zeros rather than nulls.

```
SELECT  c.country, d.date, IFNULL(i.n,0) n
  FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT country FROM inst
        ) c
  JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM inst
       ) d ON 1=1
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DATE(date) date, country, COUNT(*) n
        FROM inst
      GROUP BY DATE(date), country
       ) i ON c.country = i.country AND d.date = i.date
 ORDER BY d.date, c.country
```

Here's an example.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vab5mvJepWn2YFLJ28kGxA/0

Comment: O.Jones thank you, this works perfectly for my task!